# Pick a symbol if a value is between two numbers

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet, vba

I am struggeling with a good solution for the following problem:

[image]

As you can see I have a table with evaluation criterias on the one side and I have a score on the other side. So, `IF the score is between a certain value then a symbol(like --,-,+/-,+ or ++) should be take`.

Atm my "best" solution is to do it simply by hand. However, my score column is around 100 rows long, which takes lots of time. Furthermore, if my score column changes, then I have to start again...

Any suggestion how to do that automatically in excel?

I really appreciate your replies!

Comment: One option is to use `LOOKUP(G4,$C$4:$C$9,$B$4:$B$9)`. Just add `101` in `C9` and `=NA()` in `B9`

Comment: It can easily be solved using `INDEX/MATCH` I have the formula ready but I want you to try it first before I post a solution :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout Thx for the hint. I have not looked at the problem from this perspective, here is my `index/match` solutin: `=INDEX($B$4:$B$8;MATCH(G4;$C$4:$C$8;1))`

Comment: That is a great start. I am already typing the answer and will take some 15-20 mins so that I can explain it nicely. In the meantime why not try it out more?

Comment: @SiddharthRout Yep, will do! I am looking forward to your reply!!!

Comment: `I am looking forward to your reply!!!` Sure but before I post it, I want to see what else have you tried?

Comment: @SiddharthRout Sorry, I was not at the PC. What else do you mean, by what I tried? Is there another way? Please give me a hint!

Comment: What i meant was did you try any other combinations of Index/match to get what you want? :)

Comment: SO is not a code writing service where we give the code in a platter. And I don't want to start a wrong precedence. :) My 

answer is all typed and ready but for me to post it, I just want to see enough efforts from you. :) I may have wasted time typing the answer but in the end it's worth it ;) Am I tempted to simply submit my answer? Yes! :P But fortunately it is in check by what I mentioned earlier in this comment `I don't want to start a wrong precedence`.

Comment: @SiddharthRout Sorry, if this came wrong in your way. I do not see SO as a code writing service, much more as a plattform to learn from solved problems. My problem is, that I do not know what you would like to see from me with the `index/match` formula. Please give me a hint, I am a novice in excel formulas..

Comment: I would like to see how you think this can be solved. Some kind of theory and some formulas that you tried. Update them in your post above... As simple as that :) I understand that you are beginner with Excel formulas but that shouldn't stop you from experimenting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this formula in **H4**:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$4:$B$8,MATCH(1,(G4>=$C$4:$C$8)*(G4<=$D$4:$D$8),0)),"NOT FOUND")
```

**this is an array formula, so press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> to calculate the formula.**

Then copy/drag down the formula.

Answer (score 2):

Or try this formula:

```
=IF(G5<=20,"--",IF(AND(G5>=21,G5<=40),"-",IF(AND(G5>=41,G5<=60),"+/-"
,IF(AND(G5>=61,G5<=80),"+",IF(AND(G5>=81,G5<=100),"+","#N/A")))))
```